# Is there a way to make handles bigger in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-cs5

Whilst using the pen-tool in Adobe Illustrator, it is quite difficult to "grab" the path handles.  They are soooo very tiny!  Inkscape's handles are about twice that size.

Is there any way to get the handles bigger?  I can't find any option, and the oracle (google) doesn't report that there is any solution.  Maybe it can be done via script or addon?  Or maybe there is some hidden settings that I don't know about?

Anyone with a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the preferences of Illustrator CS6 I have the option to make the handles *slightly* bigger:

[image]

Not sure if CS5 already had the option and if it's enough of an increase for you.

Comment: Yes, I have those options too in CS5, but that *slightly* is really not as much as I want.  What good is making them just 1 pixel bigger?  Come on, Adobe!  Thanks for posting the screenshot, Bart, perhaps that will help some folks, even though it wasn't as much as I was hoping for.

Comment: @BGM I just re-read your question and saw that you want this because it's hard to grab the small handles, not because the larger handles are visually more attractive or something. Try the following: Go to `Preferences -> Smart Guides` and change the `Snapping Tolerance` to 10pt (that's the maximum). If all goes well it should be far easier to grab a handle.

Comment: That does help some, actually.  My max limit was 8pt.  I really did want bigger handles - bigger squares, that is - but this is probably as close as we're going to get.  I'll wait a little while to see if anybody has a scripting solution, and if not, I'll mark this answer.  Thanks for your time.